# How to install Mongodb driver in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I followed the steps mentioned here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gEPiIoAHo8.

I downloaded the latest stable version of it here https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb which is 1.3.4. Extracted the `php_mongodb.dll` and placed it in the `ext` in my xampp directory. Modified the `php.ini` and added `extension=php_mongodb.dll`. Downloaded the composer but just when the composer installer does its work, it gives me the error.

I tried the x64 TS (I checked my phpinfo and its thread safe) because my laptop is 64 bit but it gives me an error

> Program Output: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library  'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application. in Unknown on line 0

Tried the x84 as well (i know it wont work but i tried nontheless) and it gives me an error

> The ordinal 4694 could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll

Followed by another pop-up after the mentioned error above

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll - The operating system cannot run %1

My PHP Version is `PHP Version 5.6.3`

Xampp Version `v3.2.1 Compiled May 7th 2013`

I tried other mongoDB php driver `php_mongo.dll`, it works fine and is loaded when i do php_info. I wanted to use the `php_mongodb.dll` since the other is depreciated.

Comment: Check this out and look at the comment as well.
http://carlofontanos.com/installing-mongodb-in-xampp-windows/

Comment: @Difster The link uses the `mongo.dll` not the `mongodb.dll` from what i've heard, `mongo.dll` is depreciated. So I wanted to use the `mongodb.dll`. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 9):

1. Download the mongo driver for Windows from [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)
   Download the latest stable release by clicking on the DLL link. On the next page there is a DLL list. Make sure to pick the correct one depending on:

   - the PHP version that is installed with your XAMPP,
   - Architecture x86 or x64,
   - whether Thread Safety is enabled or disabled.
     When Thread Safety is enabled, you need to download Thread Safe (TS) version.
2. Unzip the downloaded mongo driver version and copy .dll file to XAMPP.
   After the successful download, unzip and find the .dll file. Copy it to the ext directory of your XAMPP installation. If you installed XAMPP to C drive, the full path to the ext folder would be C:\xampp\php\ext
3. Register the mongodb.dll file within php.ini
   Add the following line into php.ini file:

   extension=php_mongodb.dll
4. Restart XAMPP and refresh the phpinfo.php page
   When you restart XAMPP and refresh the phpinfo page, click CTRL+F and type mongodb, you should find infos about the just installed MongoDB Driver.
5. Install MongoDB on Windows

Note, this is quite similar to that what you did. It is essential to match the dependencies. This process worked for me several times already.

Comment: extension=mongodb
This is the right syntax and also need to set path of PHP in environment variable

Comment: please help, this is not working with me 2023
I tried a lot , php7 and php8 , downloaded many dll files from pecl but always get the error that the module is  not found in the ext/ directory, although it is exactly there

Answer (score 0):

This Issue is solved,

The solution is to get the particular version of Mongodb dll file from Github Releases and then copy the dll file to the desired location of xampp's ext folder.

Example:

My PHP Version is 8.2.4, so I need to download the Mongodb dll file which will support php 8.2.4 version which is {php_mongodb-1.15.0-8.2-ts-x64.zip} (extension_name-extension_version-php_version-windows_bit)

After downloading, extract the zip file anywhere on the pc.

Then copy the php_mongodb.dll and php_mongodb.pdb file to the xampp ext folder for me it is C:\xampp\php\ext

After that add extension=php_mongodb.dll in php.ini file.

Finally, restart the xampp apache the extension will be installed.

Thank you